# How to create CS-Cart Licensed Theme

Tags: themes, cs-cart

I would like to create a licensed CS-Cart Theme but I don't know how to implement this. Any suggestions on the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on creating themes is hosted here: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/designer_guide/index.html

If you mean that you want to sell your theme and the selling fact is a licensing fact, there are two ways of how to do that:

1) You should distribute your theme with an add-on that will perform license checking; Some other vendors are using this way.

2) We at CS-Cart are currently developing the functionality of distributing and selling add-ons and themes directly through the marketplace - you'll only need to upload an archive with your theme to the marketplace, set its price and enjoy your revenue. If you would like to join the beta-testing of this feature, please contact me.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! I have gone through that documentation already.

For #1. I figured that I really needed to have to create an add-on as well for license checking. Is this how it was done for others who are selling their licensed themes?

For #2. I would like to join in for beta-testing. I will contact you separately.